# Running PLSQL in parallel

Tags: oracle, plsql

Running PLSQL script to generate load

For some reasons (reproducing errors, ...) I would like to generate some load (with specific actions) in a PL SQL script.

What I would like to do:
A) Insert 1.000.000 rows in Schema A Table 1

B) In a loop and as best in parallel (2 or 3 times)

```
1) read from Schema-A.Table-1 one row with locking  
2) insert it to Schema-B.Table-2   
3) delete row from Schema-A.Table-1
```

Is there a way to do this B-task in a script in parallel in PLSQL on calling the script?
Who would this look like?

Comment: I think [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2) is what you're looking for.

Comment: if you want to build an Asynchronous process in PL/SQL- you can use
[DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235) or [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to parallelize SQL statements inside a PL/SQL block, instead of trying to parallelize the entire PL/SQL block:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'alter session enable parallel dml';

    insert /*+ append parallel */ into schemaA.Table1 ...
    commit;

    insert /*+ append parallel */ into schemaB.Table2 ...
    commit;

    delete /*+ parallel */ from schemaA.Table1 where ...
    commit;

    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMAA', 'TABLE1', degree => 8);
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMAB', 'TABLE2', degree => 8);
end;
/
```

Large parallel DML statements usually require less code and run faster than creating your own parallelism in PL/SQL.  Here are a few things to look out for:

1. You must have Enterprise Edition, large tables, decent hardware, and a sane configuration to run parallel SQL.
2. Setting the DOP is difficult.  Using the hint `/*+ parallel */` lets Oracle decide but you might want to play around with it by specifying a number, such as `/*+ parallel(8) */`.
3. Direct-path writes (the append hint) can be significantly faster.  But they lock the entire table and the new results won't be recoverable until after the next backup.
4. Check the execution plan to ensure that direct-path writes are used - look for the operation `LOAD AS SELECT` instead of `LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL`.  Tuning parallel SQL statements is best done with the Real-Time SQL Monitoring reports, found in `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID') from dual;`

You might want to read through the [Parallel Execution Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/parallel-exec-intro.html#GUID-F9A83EDB-42AD-4638-9A2E-F66FE09F2B43) chapter of the manual.  Oracle parallelism can be tricky but it can also make your processes runs orders of magnitude faster if you're careful.

Answer (score 0):

If objective is fast load and parallel is just an attempt to get that then do.

```
Create table newtemp as select old
```

To create table.

Then

```
Create table old_remaning as select old with not exists newtemp
```

Then drop old and new tables.  Then do rename table .  These operations will use parallel options at db level